# Enable lambda to access resources in a cross account VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have two accounts.

I have an EC2 instance in a private subnet in Account A.
I have a lambda (invoked by the API gateway) in account B that needs to access the EC2 instance in Account A.

I read about [VPC lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html), and I am able to connect the lambda to the VPCs in account B, but how do I configure this lambda to talk to the EC2 instance in account A?

Creating a VPC in account B, adding the VPC in account B to lambda, and peering the VPCs in both accounts is an option. But is there any direct way without creating a VPC in account B

Comment: What do you mean by having a Lambda function "access the EC2 instance"? Access how? Is the EC2 instance running a web server and you want the Lambda function to make a request to that web server?

Comment: if you don't want to expose your EC2 via an Elastic Load Balancer then you don't have any other choice but to use VPC peering. Hence, creating VPC in account B.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, make a request to that web server running in the EC2 instance

Answer (score 1):

A slightly 'cheating' method is to **create an additional AWS Lambda function** in Account A (`Lambda-A`), connected to the same VPC as the Amazon EC2 instance.

Then, have the existing Lambda function in Account B (`Lambda-B`) **invoke** the Lambda function in Account A (`Lambda-A`). The `Lambda-A` function can then query the EC2 instance and return information to `Lambda-B`.

This only requires `Lambda-B` to have access to the Internet to invoke `Lambda-A` via the AWS public endpoints. No fancy networking required because the AWS Lambda service is responsible for delivering the response rather than having it traverse the VPCs.

`Lambda-B` will need to wait until `Lambda-A` returns a response, so you are effectively "double-paying" for Lambda during that interval, but the cost would be minimal if the response is fast.